# How can I search by specifying a specific node with MarkLogic and get results with a snippet?

Tags: search, marklogic, code-snippets

I want to do the following for documents registered in the MarkLogic database.

1. Before searching, associate a search word with its associated document
2. Search only documents associated with search words and obtain results with snippet

If you want to get a snippet as a search result, I'd like to use Search API search: search or search: resolve functions.
However, unlike the cts: search function, these functions can not specify a node as an argument, so it seems that you can not search only for a specific node (document).

cts:search:

```
cts:search(
    $expression as node()*,
    $query as cts:query?,
    [$options as (cts:order|xs:string)*],
    [$quality-weight as xs:double?],
    [$forest-ids as xs:unsignedLong*]
) as node()*
```

search:resolve:

```
search:resolve(
    $query as element(),
    [$options as element(search:options)?],
    [$start as xs:unsignedLong?],
    [$page-length as xs:unsignedLong?]
) as element(search:response)
```

Please let me know if you are searching only for specific documents (nodes) and knowing how to obtain search results as snippets.

Comment: Does it work to have an AND query that retrieves only the documents that match the word criteria and the other query criteria?  In other words, could the queries be intersected by AND?  If appropriate, you can use search:parse() or cts:parse() to produce a query from search text, construct the AND query with the other criteria, and then call search:resolve() to produce the result report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `<searchable-expression>` that you can put in the `<search:options>`. See also:

- [search:search](http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search)
- [Options reference from search-dev guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_60011)

HTH!